# Using JavaScript to control sections in select list

Tags: javascript

I have this html code but if i have a list item like all,a,b,c,d. if i click all means it should not allow to choose other items, if i am not choosing all means it should allow to choose mulitle item from list

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="mySelect" size="5" multiple="select-multiple">
    <option>All</option>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option>d</option>
</select>
<button onclick="alert(mySelect.multiple);">Multiple</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vanilla javascript or jQuery?

Comment: You may also wish to consider a rework of your UI. There are basically 2 controls being merged into one here. It might be better to have a control that allows the user to choose between 'All' & 'Multiple' (This could be a select box or a pair of radio buttons) and then deal with the a/b/c/d options separately, but disable and/or hide these choices if 'All' is selected. The a/b/c/d options could be either a select box or a set of check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes this a doddle.

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(e){
    if($(this).find(':contains("All"):selected').length>0)
        $(this).find(':not(:contains("All")):selected').attr('selected',false);
});
```

Live example here--> http://jsfiddle.net/uaDcD/

Answer (score 0):

When the All option is clicked, loop through the list and disable the rest. Here is some sample code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function selectAllOptions(){
   var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect");
   for (i = 1; i < sel.options.length; i++){        
      sel.options[i].disabled=sel.options[0].selected;
   }
}
</script>
```

And set this function on the All option:

```
<option name="options" onClick="selectAllOptions()">All</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses jQuery, but only to get the select list element and attach the event - the rest is vanilla javascript:

```
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
    if ( this.options[0].selected ) {
        for ( var c=this.options.length-1 ; c > 0 ; c-- ) {
            this.options[c].selected = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Using the change event rather than mousedown/click means it will also work if the user is using their keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mySelect option:eq(0)").click(function(e){

        $("#mySelect option:gt(0)").attr('disabled','disabled'); 

        });

    });
    </script>
```